# MySQL Select all values from 1st column that have specific value in 2nd column

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with 2 columns.

```
+---------+-----------+
| Barcode | StationID |
+---------+-----------+
|   89411 |         1 |
|   89411 |         2 |
|   89411 |         3 |
|   89412 |         1 |
|   89413 |         1 |
+---------+-----------+
```

I would like to select all valus from Barcode column which have StationID = 1 and do NOT have a StationID different than 1.

As shown in the picture Barcode 89411 appears three times with different StationID and should be excluded from the result.

Can you help me make a query?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/52380111/2469308

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to use an `EXISTS` query:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE
    t1.StationID = 1 AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                WHERE t1.Barcode = t2.Barcode AND t2.StationID <> 1);
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=641d334c5f9e57bbdde07e4f24365f88

```
select barcode from tablename
group by barcode
having sum(case when sanctionid=1 then 0 else 1 end)=0
```

output:

```
barcode
89412
89413
```

Comment: modified it - check now , it should not return that now

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation function [GROUP_CONCAT](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php), and use `HAVING` clause to filter out those barcodes, which has only one `StationID`, that is `'1'`:

```
SELECT barcode, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT StationID) AS stations 
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY barcode 
HAVING stations = '1';
```